# Add a property to class but not store in database, django?

Tags: django

What is the best way to do this:

I have a classes(tables) A,B,C. Classes B and C have a foreign key to class A.
I want to access class B from A but i do not want to access class C from A. How to store that information in A? What is a best way? I do not want a column in db for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like you normally would. The only things that get turned into database fields are the properties that are created from the `models.___Field`-type constructors.

```
class A(models.model):
    # fields go here like normal

    def some_function(self):
        print B.SOME_CCNST
        for theB in self.myBs.all():
            pass # Do whatever

class B(models.Model):
    myA = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="myBs")
    SOME_CCNST = "Whatever"

class C(models.Model):
    myA = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="+")
```

Note that there won't be a reverse manager created in A to go to its Cs, because we set `related_name="+"`. [See the docs for more.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)